# Very slow compilation

Tags: pdftex, mac

I know this has been asked a lot but I can't figure out what is happening on my system.  Compiling even trivial documents (see below) taking upwards of 20 seconds to load, and I remember on my machine 15 years ago compilation of 10 pages of text was more or less instantaneous.  In watching to .log file run it seems like all the time is taken up by loading all the fonts, .sty files etc.  Shouldn't that just be running once, and not every time I recompile?  Here's my mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{../preamble.tex}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\end{document}
```

This takes 20 seconds to run.   I am using texshop on an otherwise very fast 2020 Mac. I can post my preamble, but it's just a number of reasonable packages.  (I can link to my .log file: [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lZx_0A2un88_RoKslB7u7_m6lidqwdEf/view?usp=sharing)  Any thoughts?  At the moment it's unbearable to be waiting 20 seconds each time to compile... Thank you!

Comment: I can add that it takes 28 seconds if I add back in my pgf and tikzpackages.   I really don't remember it being like this in the past.

Comment: Does it take the same time without preample? -remove it from your MVE. -or else what in your preample takes time?

Comment: It's very fast without preamble.  In the preamble it seems that each package just adds time to the compilation.   There are a lot of packages I load, and don't always need in each file (e.g. turning off tikz and pgf saves me 8 seconds - but this seems extreme that upon each compile it takes so long)

Comment: Find the ONE thing that takes unreasonably long, and write it directly into your MWE. Time the compilation. Write all necessary information for others to judge, like your machine info, OS, ...

Comment: Exactly how do you compile? Here I'd use the terminal as it is easier to see where the compilation "stops". Are you by any chance compiling in a folder on a cloud drive like DropBox or OneDrive?

Comment: i am compiling to a google drive folder.  I wonder if that's part of it.  let me try on a local folder.

Comment: Thank you @daleif it is down to 5 seconds when I moved it out of google drive.  That was 100% the problem.   I need to think about how to best solve this though, since I will want to do some compiling at work and at home.   I'm sure there's a solution though, and now I know where to look.

Comment: It seems that the issue is Google Drive Specific.  If I use Dropbox the problem goes away.  This is sad news, since I use Google for everything.

Answer (score -1):

I've figured out the problem: Google Drive was really slow with TexShop.  Moving everything to a local directory solved the issue.  As did moving everything to Dropbox.

I've been meaning to switch to texpad which has a Texpadtex live feature.  This feature works very fast with GoogleDrive.  These solutions are sufficient for me, and hopefully will be helpful for others.

Comment: I’ve seen another person having a problem with the latest invocation of Google Drive software.